# Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.collections.impl.utility.LazyIterate

Tags: neo4j

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on the VirtualBox, and when I try to log into the neo4j browser and create a new password, I get an error that says

"Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.collections.impl.utility.LazyIterate"

I have downloaded java via "sudo apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk, and I have also tried manally downloading a package from Oracle, but it didn't help.

I would deeply appreciate any guidance on fixing this problem.

Thank you